# Overflow scroll container bottom "cut-off" by navbar in iOS Safari

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, scrollbar, overflow

I have a scroll container consisting of several rows. The last row, however is being cut off by the nav bar at the bottom in iOS Safari and does not allow the user to see the entire content. Setting padding and margins does not resolve the issue. How do I push this content up so it can be seen when scrolling all the way down?

I am using an Xcode simulator to test this.

html

```
<div class="fixed-container">
</div>
<div class='container'>
  <div>
  </div>
  <div>
  </div>
  <div>
  </div>
  <div>
  </div>
  <div>
  </div>
</div>
```

scss

```
.fixed-container {
  flex: 1;
  height: 30vh;
  background: navy;
}

.container {
  height: 300px;
  overflow: scroll;
  border: solid 1px black;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;

  div {
      overflow-y: auto;
      background-color: pink;
      flex: 1;
      height: 100px;
      margin: 1em 0;
  }

}
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vfmncyh8/8/ or https://jsfiddle.net/vfmncyh8/8/show